# Why doesn't this ajax function that uses a url work?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

In `index.html` under body tag:

```
<a href="javascript:setTempInc()">+</a> <a href="javascript:setMode(0)">-</a>
```

and under `<head><script type="text/javascript">:`

```
var url = "get.php";

function ajaxRequest()
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            var jsondata = eval("(" + xmlhttp.responseText + ")"); //retrieve result as an JavaScript object

            document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = jsondata.y;

        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function setTempInc()
{
    var oldUrl = url;
    url = url + "9001" + jsondata.y;
    ajaxRequest();
    url = oldUrl;
}
```

I don't understand where the problem is. `url` is a string and `jsondata.y` is a int but the script doesn't work!

This function does, though:

```
function setMode(val)
{
    var oldUrl = url;
    url = url + "91" + val + "000";
    ajaxRequest();
    url = oldUrl;
}
```

Comment: Improve your question title, so, more people can help you!

Comment: Please provide the errors you are getting.

Comment: Did you checked your javascript console for errors?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that

```
var jsondata = eval("(" + xmlhttp.responseText + ")");
```

is not available to be called at

```
url = url + "9001" + jsondata.y;
```

as it is only defined inside the `ajaxRequest` function's scope.

Comment: Actually, the scope is even smaller: the `onreadystatechange` handler.

Answer (score -1):

Set variables outside functions, to use as a global variable!

This probably will work:

```
(function() {
    var url = "get.php";
    var oldUrl = '';
    var jsondata = '';

    function ajaxRequest()
    {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                jsondata = eval("("+xmlhttp.responseText+")"); //retrieve result as an JavaScript object

                document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = jsondata.y;

            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function setTempInc()
    {
        oldUrl = url;
        url = url + "9001" + jsondata.y;
        ajaxRequest();
        url = oldUrl;
    }
})();
```

Added `Closure` to avoid common security problems

Comment: I didn't provide the downvote but I assume it's because a) you're not adding anything by doing that and b) global variables should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: @MartyWallace This solve the problem, and, I can't do nothing without global variables, in this case.

Comment: @MartyWallace Added `closure`, so, global variable will be "more safe".

Comment: It's not really security that's an issue, more just code maintainability issues arise if everything is global (conflicts etc).